# Tessnet2 Init-Method crashes with certain tessdata path

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract, tessnet2

I'm using the Tessnet2 assembly (which uses Tesseract) to do OCR. Unfortunately the programm crashes without any exception after I call the init method:

```
tessnet2.Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
ocr.Init(@"D:\Test\Tessdata\german", "deu", false);
```

The german folder contains the following tesseract 2 word data:

- deu.DangAmgigs
- deu.freq-dawg
- deu.inttemp
- deu.normproto
- deu.pffmtable
- deu.unicharset
- deu.user-words
- deu.word-dawg

If I use `null` for the path it works fine because I installed tesseract on my machine. However I need a solution with the path because where the programm will be deplyoed it is not ensured that tesseract is installed.

Comment: If you installed Tesseract, chance is that the installer could have set the TESSDATA_PREFIX variable to a path different from yours. The setting is kept in the Windows' Registry. So you may want to uninstall that version, clean the Registry, and try your program again.

Comment: That was the problem. I just deleted the installed Tesseract and also deleted the environment variableTESSDATA_PREFIX and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you have Tesseract installed there is an environment variable set ( `TESSDATA_PREFIX` )which contains the path of the tessdata. To use your own path it is necessary to uninstall Tesseract and delete the environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. By the way just to confirm if I don't uninstall the Tesseract and/or do not delete the environment variable, rather just change it in my C# code to point towards my custom data path, will this effect on any of the environment that has already tesseract installed. Because I noticed that when I comment out my code that is changing the environment variable it shows me original environment variable value in the console again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the path:
     @"D:\Test\Tessdata"
```