# Tesseract Init() method C3

Tags: c#, tesseract

I am using Tesseract 2 with c# .net 4.5
Whenever code reaches to OCR.InIt() method, it comes out of code and program stops execution.
Even Catch block does not hold the code.
Please let me know how to check the problem.

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(ofd_OpenPhoto.FileName);
tessnet2.Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
ocr.Init("C:\\tessnet2\\tesseract-ocr\\tessdata", "eng", false);
```

Please let me know, how to use Init() method, Should I remove null?

```
private void btn_Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ofd_OpenPhoto.Multiselect = false;
            ofd_OpenPhoto.RestoreDirectory = true;
            ofd_OpenPhoto.SupportMultiDottedExtensions = false;
            ofd_OpenPhoto.FileName = "";
            ofd_OpenPhoto.Title = "Select Photo";
            ofd_OpenPhoto.Filter = "Photo Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";

            DialogResult result = ofd_OpenPhoto.ShowDialog();

            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string file_name;
                if (ofd_OpenPhoto.FileName != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        file_name = ofd_OpenPhoto.FileName.Substring(ofd_OpenPhoto.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                        txt_PhotoPath.Text = file_name.Substring(0, file_name.LastIndexOf("."));

                        Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> img_o = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, byte>(ofd_OpenPhoto.FileName);
                        pb_PhotoViewer_O.Image = img_o.ToBitmap();
                        if (pb_PhotoViewer_O.Image != null)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Bitmap image = new Bitmap(ofd_OpenPhoto.FileName);
                                tessnet2.Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
                                ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
                                ocr.Init(@"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR", "eng", false);
                                List<tessnet2.Word> result1 = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);
                                txt_ExtractedNumber.Text = result1.ToString();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //e.Message();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my code.
Thanks.

Comment: tessdata file haven`t extensions? Which error you have?

Comment: No error, but unexpected program getting closed...

Comment: Are you correct set filename? `tessdata` - hasn`t extension?

Comment: I am just curious to see, what are the other ways to use Init() method

Comment: Yes I have, this is the location where I have Folder Tessdata. I have copied the path from location

Comment: Tessdata is a folder?

Comment: Which File? I though I did it incorrectly....

Comment: Is it "tessnet2_64.dll"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617979/tessnet2-init-method-crashes-with-certain-tessdata-path

Comment: It was helpful, I deleted Environment Variable but still my code gets exit from the code. Don't know what is the reason?

Comment: Are you download languages? https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-2.00.eng.tar.gz&can=2&q=

Comment: Yes.This one, tesseract-2.00.eng.tar.gz

Comment: And you unpack it to C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR ?

Comment: I have folder named "C:\tessnet2\Release64" under folder I don't have Tesseract-OCR

Comment: Ok. You need unpack all files tesseract-2.00.eng.tar.gz to C:\tessnet2\Release64 and set `ocr.Init("C:\\tessnet2\\Release64", "eng", false);` It must work

Comment: I have unpacked files,
Now I have following files under folder "C:\tessnet2\Release64"
TesseractOCR.exe
TesseractOCR.exe.config
tessnet2_64.dll
tessnest2_64.pdb
along with folder tessdata, I tried copying all files from folder "tessdata" to "C:\tessnet2\Release64" but none of them worked.

Comment: OK. my final question, what files should be there at mentioned path in programme? What is I have to build a solution then what to do? can't I add some dll?

Comment: This working example of program: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76012020/ConsoleApplication1.zip, when you download, please write me

Answer (score 1):

If you write  `ocr.Init("C:\\tessnet2\\tesseract-ocr\\tessdata", "eng", false);`
then at *C:\tessnet2\tesseract-ocr\tessdata* directory you must have next files:

- *eng.DangAmbigs*
- *eng.freq-dawg*
- *eng.inttemp*
- *eng.normproto*
- *eng.pffmtable*
- *eng.unicharset*
- *eng.user-words*
- *eng.word-dawg*

**Also you must check** that an Windows system environment variable ( TESSDATA_PREFIX ) is deleted

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I checked at mentioned path all the files are present and environment variable is also deleted. Still its not working

Comment: Tesseract latest version has files under folder 32bit and 64 bit, I copied those files under main folder names Tesseract2 and application's bin/Debug folder and my task is completed. I overcame that error.